# How to return if condition from Google's AdminDirectory

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I'm trying to return different results for respective google workspace users, the problem I'm facing is... the **first answer** is returning all users.

E.g. `William Tell` and `John Peter` gets the return of `Mark Thomas` i.e. `www.google.com`

Expectation: I want to display the answer for respective users.

Where did I go wrong?

```
function getUserID() {
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var name = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName;

    if (name ="Mark Thomas") {
    greeting= "www.google.com";
    } else if (name ="William Tell"){
    greeting = "www.msn.com";
    }
    } else if (name ="John Peter"){
    greeting = "www.yahoo.com";
    }
    return greeting;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Findings:

- You need to initialize the variable named `greeting` on your script.
- You have an extra unnecessary closing bracket on the line before `else if (name ="John Peter")`
  statement.

You may test this tweaked script below:

### Modified script:

```
function getUserID() {
   var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var name = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName;
   var greeting; //"greeting" needs to be initialized for the script to work
 
   if(name == "Mark Thomas") {
   greeting= "www.google.com";
   } else if (name == "William Tell"){
   greeting = "www.msn.com";
   } else if (name == "John Peter"){
   greeting = "www.yahoo.com";
   }
 
   return greeting;
   }
```

### Test Result:

[image]

## Suggestion:

Alternatively, I suggest you use a **[Switch statement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-vs-else/)** since you have **multiple fixed conditions** instead of a nested **If-Else statement**. A switch statement is usually more efficient than a set of nested ifs.

### ***Script w/ Switch statement:***

```
function getUserID() {
   var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var name = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName.toString();
   var greeting; //"greeting" needs to be initialized to exist & be used on the script
 
   switch(name){
     case name = "Mark Thomas":
       greeting = "www.google.com";
       break;
     case name = "William Tell":
       greeting = "www.msn.com";
       break;
     case name = "Admin IJG": //Added my test account's full name to see if it works
       greeting = "www.yahoo.com";
       break;
   }
 
   return greeting;
}
```

### ***Sample Test Result:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`name ="Mark Thomas"` is an assignment not a test for equivalency.

try `name == "Mark Thomas"`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did the changes but I'm getting the same return mentioned in the post.